# 'search' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to learn C++, and I am using the `Qt` Framework. What I am currently trying to accomplish, is loading a custom font from the resource file. When I run this, `File Found` is output to the console window. When I uncomment the commented out line I get an error `'search' was not declared in this scope`. In the `Qt Creator` I have objectName set to `search`. I assumed that I could then access it like how I wrote the commented out line, but I guess I can't. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Apollo w;
    w.show();

    int fontID(-1);
    QFile res(":/lib/fonts/SourceCodePro-ExtraLight.ttf");
    if(res.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == true){
        fontID = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFontFromData(res.readAll());
        if(fontID == -1){
            qDebug() << "File Not Found";
        }else{
            qDebug() << "File Found";
        }
    }
    //search.setFont(QFont("Source Code Pro ExtraLight", 26));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of `search`? the code where you define this object.

Comment: Learning a language with the help of a GUI constructor that generates code for you is not a very good idea.

Comment: @n.m. That is how I learn, I start with a GUI, then as I start to understand what the GUI did/does I then start doing it without the GUI. That is how learned Java. I used a GUI Builder that generated code, now I don't use one and can write Java without it. I am doing the same thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object names is "search".

The object is a part of the GUI I guess, so if you want to have acces to it you should do something like that:

```
ui->search->setFont(...);
```

Qt creator is quite smart and offer you a kind of auto complement. If it doesn't offer you a proposition for a object of the GUI most of the time that mean you do it wrong.

Comment: `ui` isn't defined in this file, but is defined in another file. Should I place the code there instead?

Comment: I was having a SUPER hard time getting this, then I saw that I was setting font styles in my stylesheet, which was overpowering the font I actually wanted.